# how do i make automation in robot skip this download check?

Tags: automation, robotframework, browser-automation, webautomation

When I click on the link manually, it does not ask for this validation, but when I click on the link via automation, it asks for this validation, how to make it not ask for this validation

follows the image of the validation that is requested and its description.

```
**This type of file can harm your computer, do you want to keep the file anyway?

[Keep] [Discard]**
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCPY6.png

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
${message}=  Handle Alert  action=DISMISS  #Click on 'Cancel' button
```

Comment: but you can't map this element.

Would this ${message} be the message mapping or not?

Comment: it is just to save status, you can ignore and run just a keyword